# Serialize is pumping out blank arrays

Tags: php, jquery, html, javascriptserializer

So I am trying to send form data through ajax and am using serialize to do so. I have tried serializeArray as well and am getting the same results. I was hoping someone might be able to help me troubleshoot because I feel like i have tried everything. Please view  a snippet of my code below:

```js
function quizSubmit($quiz){
      console.log($quiz);
      var form='#'+$quiz;

      var data1=$(form).serializeArray();
      console.log(data1);
       $.ajax({
         type  : 'POST',
         url  : 'quizsubmit.php?quiz='+$quiz,
         data : data1,
         beforeSend : function() {
             $('#checklist-info-container').html('processing');
               console.log("sending");
         },
         error : function() {
             $('#checklist-info-container').html('failure');
               console.log("fail");
         },
         // success callback
         success : function (response) {
             $('#checklist-info-container').html(response);
               console.log("success");
         },
         timeout : 3000,
       })
    }
```

```html
<table class="checklist-table">
              <form id="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="q1" method="post">
              <tr>
                <td class="checklist-info-title"><?php echo($title); ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="checklist-info-description"><div>
                  <div class="form-group required quiz-question">
                    <label class="control-label" for="question1">What did you learn?</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer1">Nothing</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer2">Something</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required quiz-question">
                    <label class="control-label" for="question2">Question 2</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer1">Answer 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer2">Answer 2</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required quiz-question">
                    <label class="control-label" for="question3">Question 3</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question3" value="answer1">Answer 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question3" value="answer2">Answer 2</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required quiz-question">
                    <label class="control-label" for="question4">Question 4</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question4" value="answer1">Answer 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="question4" value="answer2">Answer 2</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="quiz-button"><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="quizSubmit(<?php echo $id; ?>);">Submit</button></td>
              </tr>
            </form>
            </table>
```

The second console log print out keeps printing an array of length 0 with nothing in it. but am not sure why.

Comment: Is `$quiz` a string or a jQuery object when passed to that function?

Comment: What is your first console log printing. console.log($quiz);

Comment: My first console log prints out the id of the form which is "q1" (its actual showing the entire form element: <form id="q1" name="q1" method="post"></form>

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your javascript code. Replace $quiz to quiz

```
function quizSubmit(quiz){
  console.log(quiz);
  var form='#'+quiz;

  var data1=$(form).serializeArray();
  console.log(data1);
  .......
  .......
}
```

jQuery sets the global $ variable to an object with a number of special behaviors, so variables beginning with $ are often reserved for variables orvalues related to jQuery.

In you are html code you are not passing variable as jquery object. it seems you are passing as javascript variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried that and it is still giving me an empty array. I am completely at a loss. Any other suggestions?